# Install a custom empty module break my custom style

Tags: 8

On Drupal 8, I have a style and a **empty** module :

/modules/kyna/nature/

/modules/kyna/nature/nature.info.yml

```
name: 'Nature Theme Structure and configuration'
type: module
description: 'Example Module description'
package: Kyna
version: VERSION
core: 8.x
```

When my module is installed and the cache clear, my custom theme is broken:

[image]
Why my custom and empty module break my custom theme please ?
Without the addon all is OK:
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your custom theme called nature?

That's not allowed, you can't have modules and themes with the same name.